# Migration admin.0004_auto_20200625_1615 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('staff', '0001_initial')

Tags: django

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMRHy.jpg)django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration admin.0004_auto_20200625_1615 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('staff', '0001_initial')

Answer (score 0):

You've deleted the 0001_initial.py migration file.
The migrations files are connected with each other like a chain. Every new migration (except initial) needs to have a reference. So your initial migration doesn't exist in your migration folder.